# Implementing custom uniq in linux shell development

Tags: c, shell, uniq

I'm developing a custom shell. In this assignment, I need to implement uniq-like command. Given sorted lines, *uniq* should be able to print all unique values and (their number of occurences if the command is **uniq -c**). Example code is stated at the very end.

I have no problem with the algorithm. I wrote a function which can do take exactly same operation with desired one. However, the problem is that, what are these types of outputs and inputs? I mean when I command *cat input.txt*, are these lines just one string or are they given in array? As I said, algorithm is ok but I do not know how to apply that correct algorithm in the shell? Any help or idea is appreciated.

```
$cat input.txt
Cinnamon
Egg
Egg
Flour
Flour
Flour
Milk
Milk
```

```
$cat input.txt | uniq
Cinnamon
Egg
Flour
Milk
```

Comment: These lines are writing in the console. How you implement it internally - is your consideration.

Comment: I understand that. If these lines were in a txt file, I can open this txt file by fopen and pass the file descriptor to the function. But in that case, **cat input.txt** is not a file to pass. How can I tell my function to do the operation on output of cat?

Comment: You may say that use directly input.txt, however it can be ls | uniq also.

Comment: You use the `pipe()` function to create a pipe between the process running `cat` and the process running `uniq`.

Comment: If you are implementing a true shell, the `cat` will be either  an internal command or external executable. In case of internal command - you simply execute it and send the output to `stdout`. In case of external executable you need to create a process with pipe connected to it's output. Get the output from pipe and decide what to do with it - send to `stdout` or another piped process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> are these lines just one string or are they given in array

These lines are the result of a fork, just strings that have been sent to `stdout`.

`getline` is very useful in these cases, now that you have the algorithm, you only have to process the output of `cat`.

An example:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *str = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    ssize_t len = 0;
    int line = 1;

    while ((len = getline(&str, &size, stdin)) != -1)
    {
        printf("%2d) length = %2zd | %s", line++, len, str);
    }
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
gcc -o demo demo.c
cat demo.c | ./demo
```

Output:

```
 1) length = 32 | #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
 2) length =  1 | 
 3) length = 19 | #include <stdio.h>
 4) length = 20 | #include <stdlib.h>
 5) length = 23 | #include <sys/types.h>
 6) length =  1 | 
 7) length = 15 | int main(void)
 8) length =  2 | {
 9) length = 22 |     char *str = NULL;
10) length = 21 |     size_t size = 0;
11) length = 21 |     ssize_t len = 0;
12) length = 18 |     int line = 1;
13) length =  1 | 
14) length = 54 |     while ((len = getline(&str, &size, stdin)) != -1)
15) length =  6 |     {
16) length = 61 |         printf("%2d) length = %2zd | %s", line++, len, str);
17) length =  6 |     }
18) length = 15 |     free(str);
19) length = 14 |     return 0;
20) length =  2 | }
21) length =  1 |
```

Comment: That was a really good answer! Can I ask a follow up question? What if I wanted to add those **lines** to a string array? It is so easy in Java or etc with some *append* method however in C, I am confused since arrays must be predefined.

Comment: It depends on your algorithm, if you are using `qsort` you need to collect those lines into an array of pointers to `char`, in this case `realloc` is your friend, give it a try and come back if you have problems :)

Comment: I could not figure out how to do that...

Comment: I do not use qsort, the list is already sorted :)

Comment: https://ideone.com/rAdc13

Comment: Please, check the new version of the question.

Comment: solved it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The format is a sequence of bytes. How you store that is up to you. Your design choice.

`cat input.txt` opens the file `input.txt` and reads the bytes and sends them to the "screen" (standard output).

`uniq` reads bytes from the "keyboard" (standard input) and... does the unique stuff. And sends the output to the "screen". You can try this yourself if you want - just run `uniq` by itself, or `uniq -c` - to stop the command and make it process the last line, press enter to finish the line, then Ctrl-D.

When you do `cat input.txt | uniq` the shell runs `cat input.txt`, and it runs `uniq`, but it redirects `cat`'s "screen" to `uniq`'s "keyboard". So it's like you run `cat input.txt` and then whatever it displays, you type that into `uniq`.

As I understand it you are writing a "pretend" shell, and yours won't actually run the two commands and connect them, so you aren't interested in how to do that, only how to simulate it.

Something to be aware of is that the bytes go straight from `cat` to `uniq`. It doesn't save them all into a stream first. Therefore if the first command was a slow one, `uniq` would be able to process the lines as soon as they were ready, and it wouldn't have to wait for the first command to finish before it could start doing the uniq stuff. With your `cat` command, you can't tell the difference, unless the file is really big and won't fit in a string, but you may notice it with other commands.

For your pretend shell it might be simplest to process one line at a time through all the commands in order.

Answer (score 0):

> when I command *cat input.txt*, are these lines just one string or are they given in array?

If you are executing the external `cat` command<sup>*</sup> then the output is written to that command's standard output.  This is I/O, not shared memory.  Once those data emerge from `cat`, it is no longer appropriate to characterize them in terms of whatever internal data structure `cat` used for them.  They are just a sequence of characters.  If another command consumes those data then it chooses its own data structures for handling them.

And how *would* your `uniq` consume those data? One of two ways:

1. The output of `cat` would be redirected to a file, which `uniq` would afterward open and read.

   ```
   cat input.txt > temp; uniq temp
   ```

   OR
2. The output of `cat` would be redirected to the standard input of `uniq`.

   ```
   cat input.txt | uniq
   ```

It is one of the organizing principles of UNIX that every I/O endpoint is logically a file, and therefore can be handled more or less the same.  In case (1) you would `open()` or `fopen()` the named file, whereas in case (2) you would use the preconnected file descriptor 0 or `stdin` stream, but once you decide which of those to use, it's the same either way.

---

<sup>*</sup>And if you are executing your own internal `cat` then you know the details better than we do.